# Napili Template. Record Banner not respecting page layout changes on Account or presenting custom object page layouts

Tags: lightning-aura-components, napili

I basically want to customize what fields are displayed on the Record Banner.  Documentation says change the page layout but when I do, nothing happens.  Any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

To customize the banner of the record you will need to change compact layouts for the object .

Every object has a compact layout .A sample compact layout for Account is shown below
[image]